# parsing a CSV as XML via PHP

Tags: php, xml, csv

I found this script which parses a CSV file to XML. Problem is it seems to only be getting the first line of data after the column headers.

```
function csv2xml($file, $container = 'data', $rows = 'row')
{
        $r = "<{$container}>\n";
        $row = 0;
        $cols = 0;
        $titles = array();

        $handle = @fopen($file, 'r');
        if (!$handle) return $handle;

        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE)
        {
             if ($row > 0) $r .= "\t<{$rows}>\n";
             if (!$cols) $cols = count($data);
             for ($i = 0; $i < $cols; $i++)
             {
                  if ($row == 0)
                  {
                       $titles[$i] = $data[$i];
                       continue;
                  }

                  $r .= "\t\t<{$titles[$i]}>";
                  $r .= $data[$i];
                  $r .= "</{$titles[$i]}>\n";
             }
             if ($row > 0) $r .= "\t</{$rows}>\n";
             $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
        $r .= "</{$container}>";

        return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your CSV may be using Carriage Returns instead of Newlines, Try changing the "\n"s to "\r"s.